# How can i do html decode text returning from html helper? cakephp 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I am use this.

```
echo  html_entity_decode(
      $this->Form->postLink( '<i class="fa fa-fw fa-remove"></i>Delete',
                             ['action' => "delete",$item->id],
                             ['confirm' => 'Are you sure?'])
      );
```

No problems here but I want to don't use html_entity_decode. Do you have another solution?

```
echo     $this->Form->postLink( '<i class="fa fa-fw fa-remove"></i>Delete',
                                 ['action' => "delete",$item->id],
                                 ['confirm' => 'Are you sure?']);
```

Result: `<i class="fa fa-fw fa-remove"></i>Delete`

Comment: Why you don't want to use `html_entity_decode` ?

Comment: because ['confirm' => 'Are you sure?'] does not work.

Comment: And why it doesn't work ?

Comment: it doesn't work for use html_entity_decode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo     $this->Form->postLink( '<i class="fa fa-fw fa-remove"></i>Delete',
                             ['action' => "delete",$item->id],
                             ['confirm' => 'Are you sure?','escape'=>false]);
```

You could correct with this params